# How to Disable installing/upgrading Extensions in Visual Studio Code (VS Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Looking for suggestions/settings on how we can disable users from installing/upgrading extensions in Visual Studio Code (VS Code) at an enterprise level. We would want users to go through vulnerability  evaluation before requesting install for any new extension.